# How to connect android app to parse?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, parse-server

I am making an android app which demands to get Data like User's Name,E-mail Id,Mobile no,Postal address,College Name,etc.I Have created a form for that.I was thinking to get this Data through by connecting my App to Parse.I have installed Parse Sdk in my project but it is asking me to provide Url as far as Parse Documentation is concerned.

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(myContext)
.applicationId("YOUR_APP_ID")
.server("http://YOUR_PARSE_SERVER:1337/parse")

...

.build());
```

What should be that parse server Url?
Else,Is there any anything better than Parse for me if I want to make it in a day or as soon as possible!
Hope someone will help me n this Regard.Thanks in advance!

Comment: leave parse and get start with firebase....

Comment: If you are not familiar with Parse, you can try firebase.

Comment: I decided to go with firebase,but I am getting problem in saving data based on user input through spinner.I dont know actually, how can I save data to firebase through spinner?I got success with int and String bit dont know how to deal with spinner in this regard?Please help!

Answer (score 0):

sitepoint has a really detailed tutorial on using parse - [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-cloud-backend-android-app-using-parse/)

Although its abit unclear what your actually asking..

Comment: Parse is asking for parse server url while connecting to android app.What should be that Url.

Answer (score 0):

use your ipv4 ip address as your server url. Make sure to implement the changes both on server index.js file and Parse.Initialize function in android code.